# R: ggplot - plotting a trend line of datapoint with different colors based on group

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, point

Assume I have a dataframe df:

```
Day   Value   Group
1     1       1
2     5       1
3     10      2
4     15      2
5     20      1
```

I would like to trend a **single** line on df, x = Day & y = Value, but with each points colored based on Group

Here's a rough illustration for better understanding:
[image: Single line trend with colored points]

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `color=` aesthetic to only one layer if needed.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(Day, Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Group)), size = 2)
```

[image: ggplot2]

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Day   Value   Group
1     1       1
2     5       1
3     10      2
4     15      2
5     20      1")
```